# 'pyuic5' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, cmd, pyqt5, pyuic

I am a beginner in making GUI by `python_pyqt5`.
I can't convert the UI file into a `py` file, whenever I try to convert I get this message from CMD:

```
pyuic5` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I search for pyqt5 library in this direction `C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts`. I didn't find it, although I have download `pyqt5` and its tools with pip from the last direction but the `pyqt5` located in this direction: `C:\Users\mee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts`.
I don't know what to do if you could help me, please.

Comment: When you installed python you didn't point to its path being added to the PATH, try adding `C:\Users\mee\AppData\Roaming\Python` to the PATH of the environment variables.

Comment: thank you, Mario. I reinstall python and add the path to it. it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

try using **pip install pyqt5_tools --pre**